# Grails 2.4.0 bug with list?

Tags: grails

I was using this same snippet under 2.3.7 yesterday which worked fine, but under Grails 2.4.0 it returns only the first object.

Just wondering if it is something dodge on my end or if indeed in 2.4.0 that the first line is returned on output. If you comment out the `countries <<` line it prints it all to console, with that line enabled it just returns 1 record.

```
def listCountries() {
    def countries = []
    def locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales().find { availableLocale ->
        def lang=availableLocale?.getLanguage()?.toString()
        def country=availableLocale.getCountry().toString() ?: lang
        println "---"+lang+"---"+country
        countries << "${lang},${country}"
    }

    render countries
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `.each` or is it `.find` after `getAvailableLocales`? If you are using find, with the last line evaluating to groovy truth it would just work for first iteration.

Comment: do you mean `findAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to look at. First of all `countries` is a list instead of a map. :)

The logic in `listCountries` can be drilled down as below:

```
def listCountries() {
    render Locale.availableLocales?.collect { 
        "${it.language.toString()},${it.country.toString()}" 
    }
}
```

[**`find`**](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) will only return the first result when a condition is satisfied or evaluates to Groovy True, hence it prints only once in your case.

Comment: Thank you yes this was the issue